# Powershell Invoke-WebRequest could not create ssl/tls secure channel when tls is upgrade to tls1.3

Tags: .net, powershell, tls1.3, udeploy

there is a powershell script running as a remote process on uDeploy, below is the script:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://xxx/api/health
```

it was working fine until the service of this api (running on openshift) is using tls1.3, then I have to remove

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
```

but still got the error `Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel`
then I had to copy this script to my local environment which has .net 5 and .net framework 4.8 installed and the script can perfectly work without adding something like:

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls13
```

Can I assume that .net framework 4.8 doesn't support tls1.3 but .net 5 does?

So the question is, is there a way to Invoke-WebRequest using .net framework 4.8 to a tls1.3 service?
BTW, I know there could be a way by editing the Registry and enable tls1.3, but this is forbidden in our environment

Added windows versions for both my local environment that can run the script:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
10     0      19042  0
```

And the remote environment on uDeploy services that cannot run the script:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
6      3      9600   0
```

Comment: This may help if using win10 https://www.itechtics.com/tls-1-3/#:~:text=TLS%201.3%20is%20not%20enabled,TLS%201.3%20in%20Windows%2010

Comment: I think the OS actually running the process is a window server and it will not be changed to win10, but my I tested the script on my local environment and it is win10 and it is working fine

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Exact build number please `winver`

Comment: I am using [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version instead, and in my local environment that has not problem is 
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
10     0      19042  0    
the remote environment cannot run the script is :
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
6      3      9600   0

Comment: You still left out the name of hte windows release, found the above is Server 2012 R2 though. A quick google reveals Server 2012 does not support TLS 1.3. - if you'd like to run TLS1.3 with uDeploy you'll need a server running an OS that isn't a decade old ;)